# Jquery generate input element with XY value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate input element which contain value like coordinate XY.

This image will explain what im looking for.

[image: Character for Column and Number for Row]

From image above so the value of each input are A1, B1, C1, ..., D5, E5.
I have defined the size of number input generated, 5x5.

Below is my code to generate element plus increment number for value.
But i dont know how to modify it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var a = 5, b = 5, val = a*b;

   $("#seatwrapper").each(function() {
      var arrseat = new Array();
      arrseat['this'] = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'X'];

      var abcd = new Array();
      abcd['this'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']; // I have no idea to add Increment Character as Column ID

      // go thru the main array
      for (var key in arrseat) {
         // go thru the inner arrays
         var arr = arrseat[key];
         for (i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
            var _select = $('<input></input>', {class: 'seat dropdown ' + arr[i] + '', name: 'seatlist', type: 'text', value: i+1});
            $("#seatwrapper").append(_select);
         }
      }       
   });  
   $('#seatwrapper').css('width',b*40+6);
});
```

Here's live demo in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/weq/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed [JS Bin!](http://jsbin.com/feqizike/10/edit)

But you have some warnings at the bottom!

you needed to count the row and with some modular arithmetic, voila!

Comment: What '5' stands for in value: abcd[(i % 5)]? row or column?
I want to make it dynamic, maybe the size not 5x5. So i defined var a & b at the first.

Comment: oh sorry, both 5s are the number of columns! i changed your variable names to clarify: http://jsbin.com/feqizike/11/edit